# How to overwrite a default value for argument in Python?

Tags: python, default

I import a class from a library and this class uses a variable/constant which is defined inside the library but outside the class. Is it possible for me to change that value?

I probably need to change `HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30` to something else.

```
HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30
      
class RawProxy(object):
    # FIXME: need a CChainParams rather than hard-coded service_port
    def __init__(self, service_url=None,
                       service_port=8332,
                       btc_conf_file=None,
                       timeout=HTTP_TIMEOUT,
                       _connection=None):
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `p = RawProxy(timeout=60)` (or whatever you want the timeout to be)?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value of `HTTP_TIMEOUT` just serves as default to the `timeout` parameter of the `RawProxy.__init__` method, you can simply specify your desired timeout as argument to the class instantiation, for example:

```
p = RawProxy(timeout=60)
```